# What is the best practice in react.js to use a constants value in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If a child component requires a globally settable constant, such as the available booking time, for example: `SESSION_ RANGE = [9, 17]`.

I need to parse it into a function (`sessionCreator`) first.
What the child component really accepts is an array of objects (sessionData).

Then I need to use this in the parents component :
`const sessionData = sessionCreator(SESSION_RANGE);`

However, there are several options that I can choose:
1. Inside the render() of the parent component. 
2. Create a `getSessionData` function inside the class, and then use the code above inside the `getSessionData` function.

Given this use case, what is the best practice to use for the parents component?

```
const sessionData = sessionCreator(SESSION_RANGE);
```

```
import { SESSION_RANGE } from '../../constants/setting';
import { sessionCreator } from '../../utils/function';
//option3

class Parent extends Component {
  //option2

  render(){
    // option 1
    return (
      <Child dataSource={sessionData} />
    )
```

Comment: can you show your components?

Answer (score 1):

If this is constant and will never change, then I would put it outside of the component because when the component re-renders - the constant will be recreated for no reason.

Comment: Yes, That's what I'm concerned about.